# Prevent GRUB from recognizing Windows volume

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, windows-7

I have a dual-boot system, that has Windows 7 with a McAfee Encrypted Endpoint volume, and Ubuntu 12.04 (3.5.0 kernel) on a totally separate (expansion bay) volume.

Currently the system (a laptop) boots just fine into either system, if either:

1. I physically remove the drive containing the system not being used.
2. I boot into the BIOS and select the drive containing the system that I want.

I want to keep it this way. Over the past few months (ever since the McAfee Encryption was enabled) at various times I have had McAfee corrupt the (pre-McAfee) Windows volume GRUB MBR, and had a GRUB2 update corrupt the Windows 7 McAfee EE MBR, to the point that one or the other system was inaccessible.

Now, I have reached a stable point where the Win 7 volume seems to know nothing about the Ubuntu Volume, and visa versa.  But because the last corruption occurred during the GRUB 1.99 update (and subsequent auto-invocation of update-grub) I am worried each time I see a new kernel pushed out.  I have been removing my Win-7 volume before updating the kernel just to be safe, so that there is no way GRUB even sees it.

**But is there a way to permanently tell GRUB that under no circumstances should it touch the Windows Volume?**  BIOS selection isn't as friendly as GRUB, but it seems to be safer... and I still want to use GRUB to switch between Ubuntu kernel versions.

Comment: Suggestion: You could keep windows and ubuntu in separate drives and make ubuntu the first drive (by connecting the hard drive with ubuntu to the first sata connector, check your motherboard manual, upon boot it should be the first drive in the list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grub2 remembers where to reinstall on major updates. You should change that setting.

To see what drive grub2 uses see this line   - grub-pc/install_devices:

```
sudo debconf-show grub-pc

sudo grub-probe -t device /boot/grub
```

If you un-select everything or install to a partition which we never recommend, it will not reinstall to a drive's MBR. 
Re-check with above on install_device setting.

to get grub2 to remember where to reinstall on updates:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Enter thru first pages,spacebar to choose/unchoose drive, enter to accept, do not choose partitions